# Where to build code coverage from PHPUnit to access it from localhost for a symfony2 project?

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, phpunit, code-coverage

Currently the code coverage reports are stored in:

`app/build/coverage`

Trying to access the folder through localhost, I receive a

```
403 error: Forbidden,
You  don't have permission to access path/to/root/app/build on this server.
```

**My questions are:**

1. **Is `app/build` the correct location** to build code coverage reports?
2. **How can I access them from localhost?**
3. In any case, why is the access forbidden? **How does Symfony tell the server to not access this directory?** (I have searched for a answer looking at the various `.htaccess` but I didn't find anything related - apparently - to the `app` directory).

Comment: Did you try symlinking the app/build into the web directory?

Comment: But doing this i'll have the coverage reports publicly available o.O I'll never do somthing like this... Or i'm not considering somthing relevant?

Comment: Only if you deploy the `app/build` directory to your production server it will be be public. I was under the assumption that you were trying to set it up for your development machine. Also, you can use different allow/deny rules, e.g. for  [apache2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) or for [apache2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html)

Comment: This is a very good point, you are right!

Comment: But in this case, isn't it more convenient to configure PHPUnit to output the coverage reports directly into the web directory?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a new Apache VHost, and symlink the build directory into that

```
cd  /web/ci/public
ln -fs ~/repo/symfony-project/build  symfony-project

# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ci.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName ci.local

    DocumentRoot /web/ci/public
    <Directory /web/ci/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ci.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ci.access.log combined
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
# so: http://ci.local/symfony-project are the build artifacts
```

Comment: Is  a solution very similar to the one suggested by K0pernikus in a comment to my question: as i told there, i think that doing this will expose coverage reports to public and i don't think this is a good thing... Or not?

Comment: You don't put this stuff on a public server. It's for development. You run it on you local machine. If you have no where else to put it, you could protect it with passwords or IP lockouts.

Comment: But in this case, isn't it more convenient to configure PHPUnit to output the coverage reports directly into the web directory?